Traveling as a Swedish citizen with Argentinian wife who overstayed in Germany
My wife and I will be travelling from Argentina to Sweden with a layover in Frankfurt on the 24th of May 2024. Last time (2024-04-17) she got stopped and an officer opened a case stating she overstayed her visa.
She was staying in Norway with a 1-year working holiday visa as we were waiting to get an answer from the Swedish migration agency for our partnership visa. We thought that the 90 days started automatically after that visa but it turns out we were wrong.
We are wondering if this will be a problem at the border in Germany. Note that we got married while in Argentina and that we where not married during out last layover in Frankfurt.
She now has a Swedish visa, which was approved after this and married to me, a Swedish national. We called the prosecutor's office and they have not started the case.

Now that you are married, she has the same rights or freedom of movement in the EU as you (as a family member of an EU citizen), as long as she is traveling with you or traveling to join you. When in Sweden, national Swedish laws apply on her status, but in other EU countries, she is protected by the freedom of movement laws when with you.

Thank you! Also what could be the reproccussions? As we already paid a 110€ fine. Could this lead to a ban? She already has her swedish visa…

Actually, it's far from obvious that you were wrong, that's a “rule” Germany made up and as Mark pointed out, the Schengen Borders Code is in the process of being amended to clarify that it was never meant to be that way. You were technically in Germany but applying it on a layover when the country where you were actually staying potentially did not have any problem with it sounds like overreach to me. And initiating some proceedings that would almost certainly go nowhere over this is even more questionable. But all of this is moot now that you are married and travelling together.


Last time she got stopped and an officer opened a case stating she overstayed her visa.
...
We are wondering if this will be a problem at the border In germany.
...
We called the prosecutor's office and they have not started the case.

This will not cause a problem. Only a judge can order an alert to be entered into the SIS system (Alerts and data in SIS) after a conviction. Since 'they have not started the case', no entry will have been made.

Note that we got married while in Argentina and that we where not married during out last layover in Frankfurt.
She now has a Swedish visa, which was approved after this and married to me, a Swedish national.

For the layover in Frankfurt, you and your spouse will enter based on Article 6 (Right of residence for up to three months) of DIRECTIVE 2004/38/EC (Freedom of Movement).
The conditions of Article 6 Entry conditions for third-country nationals of the Schengen Border Code do not apply to your spouse when 'accompanying or joining the Union citizen'.


Article 2
Definitions (Schengen Border Code)
...
5. ‘persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union law’ means:
(a) Union citizens within the meaning of Article 20(1) TFEU, and third-country nationals who are members of the family of a Union citizen exercising his or her right to free movement to whom Directive 2004/38/EC of the European Parliament and of the Counci  applies;
...
6. ‘third-country national’ means any person who is not a Union citizen within the meaning of Article 20(1) TFEU and who is not covered by point 5 of this Article;
...


Some knowledgeable shit here dude!  FTW

Thank you! Also what could be the reproccussions? As we already paid a 110€ fine. Could this lead to a ban? She already has her swedish visa…

@JoelAlexAK You wrote that they have not started the case, so what was the fine for? A ban is very unlikely.

The officer at the border told us that by paying 110€ at the spot the process would be accelerated. But it appears that it was not the case as we called them 4 days ago and they told us we would have to wait quite a lot.

@JoelAlexAK That sounds very strange. Can you add an image of the receipt to your question (with the personal data blotted out)?

While reading the papers again it appears to be a bail payment. I could not attach pictures for some reason. But why would a bail payment be necessary?

@JoelAlexAK The max image size is 2 Mib,which may be one reason. Without reading the text I can't help further. Press 'Edit' on your question and upload the image.

Hello, i added the receipt! Many thanks!!

@JoelAlexAK It's a prepayment in case you are found guilty by the court later ("security for the proceedings") since they cannot realistically collect from persons abroad. If the case is officially closed (e.g. dismissed by the prosecutor), you could get it back but it's probably not worth your time and effort to deal with a number of foreign bureaucrats. But you also consented to the stay of proceeding by forfeiting the bail, so the procedure is likely stayed instead of dismissal on other grounds; then you cannot get the money back, but it is also technically not a fine/criminal punishment.

@JoelAlexAK If you have a Swedish Bank account, supply them the IBAN number in case of a refund. When the expected changes to the Schengen Border Code comes into effect (Can I leave Poland before my student visa expires and come back into Poland without issue (after the visa has expired) to fly home to the US?) this question will become moot.

Thank you everyone for calming us down with this situation!
